# using asyncio with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, asynchronous, mysql-python

I'm trying to understand `asyncio` and how to use it with MySQLdb. I think I just don't understand how asyncio works. For example, let's say I want to asynchronously do two queries at the same time. For example, without async and I'm doing two queries then I might do it like

```
import MySQLdb

def test1():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    conn.query('FIND * FROM table1')
    return conn.store_result().fetch_row(numrows=0, how=1)
    conn.close()

def test1():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    conn.query('FIND * FROM table2')
    return conn.store_result().fetch_row(numrows=0, how=1)
    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo1 = test1()
    foo2 = test2()
```

And this is slow because it needs to finish the query from `test1()` before even starting `test2()`. My understanding is that this is where `asyncio` helps because it can start a function and then let go control to do a second function. I thought you did this by making a function into an asynchronous function using `async` and then said where to wait in the function with `await`, but I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding that. This is what I am trying to do:

```
import asyncio
import MySQLdb

async def test1():
    conn = await MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    await conn.query('FIND * FROM table1')
    conn.close()
    return conn.store_result().fetch_row(numrows=0, how=1)

async def test1():
    conn = await MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    await conn.query('FIND * FROM table2')
    conn.close()
    return conn.store_result().fetch_row(numrows=0, how=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = sayncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(test1(), test2()))
    loop.close()
```

And this doesn't work. Is there a way to make asynchronous queries with MySQLdb in this way? I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: I believe it doesn't work at all right?

Comment: That's not how it works. The answer is you can't make async queries that way. For one thing, the method after the `await` must return an "awaitable", such as a coroutine. 
You could use threads to parallelize this .

Answer (score 2):

You really misunderstood async. You should first have an async lib to get async support. Obviously `MySQLdb` is not.

Take a look at https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql